# What is the SQL query for Orchestration debugger information (tracking data) in BizTalk?

Tags: biztalk, tracking, orchestration

By using the Orchestration debugger one can get useful time information on the left, regarding entering and leaving shapes. Unfortunately one cannot copy the information from that window. I would like to do some benchmarks and save statistics in Excel.

Does anyone know the sql query to get the same data from the DB? I have tried to find out with SQL Profiler, but did not hit anything that looks like the correct query or stored procedure.

I know I could use BAM, but I just need a quick one for temporary use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to watch with SQL trace be sure you have stopped BizTalk  and you are looking at the BizTalkDTADb database otherwise it is guaranteed to be an exercise in futility as BizTalk constantly interacts with SQL Server.

The exact stored procedure it calls to display the orchestration info is dtasp_LocalCallGetActions.  You will likely have to do some fancy joins to get some meaningful data out of it.  A good place to start is the views in the BizTalkDTADb database which can show the same data you see in the HAT views and will allow you to run the same queries over in query analyzer.